# difference between SSBO and Image load/store

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

What are the diffences between "Shader Storage Buffer Objects" (SSBO) and Image load store operations

When should one be used and not the other?

They both can have atomic operations and I assume they are stored in the same type of memory. And regardless if they are stored in the same type of memory, do they have the same performance characteristics?

edit: the original question was asking between SSBOs and Uniform buffer objects, it was meant to be between SSBO and Image load store.

Comment: Another difference is that in GLSL ES "Except for image variables qualified with the format qualifiers r32f, r32i, and r32ui, image variables must specify either memory qualifier readonly or the memory qualifier writeonly." See https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.1/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.10.pdf (true for OpenGL ES 3.2 too)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between shader storage buffer objects and image textures and why one would want to use them is that they can use interface blocks.

Images are just textures which mean only vec4's are in the data structure. Well not only vec4, it could have other formats, but the data structure would be many of one data type.

Where as, SSBO's are generic. They can use combinations of int's, float's, arrays of vec3's all in a single interface block.

So, SSBO's are much more flexible than just Image Texture's.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is already answered more or less definitively at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object.  It says:

> SSBOs are a lot like Uniform Buffer Objects. Shader storage blocks are
> defined by Interface Block (GLSL)s in almost the same way as uniform
> blocks. Buffer objects that store SSBOs are bound to SSBO binding
> points, just as buffer objects for uniforms are bound to UBO binding
> points. And so forth.
>
> The major differences between them are:
>
> 1. SSBOs can be much larger. The smallest required UBO size is 16KB; the smallest required SSBO size is 16MB, and typical sizes will
>    be on the order of the size of GPU memory.
> 2. SSBOs are writable, even atomically; UBOs are uniform​s. SSBOs reads and writes use incoherent memory accesses, so they need the
>    appropriate barriers, just as Image Load Store operations.
> 3. SSBOs can have unbounded storage, up to the buffer range bound; UBOs must have a specific, fixed storage size. This means that you can
>    have an array of arbitrary length in an SSBO. The actual size of the
>    array, based on the range of the buffer bound, can be queried at
>    runtime in the shader using the length​ function on the unbounded
>    array variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the question was comparing the wrong objects. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, SSBOs have much larger storage and supports atomic operations, the accepted answer also mentioned that SSBOs are generic in the sense that they allow users to combine different types. But personally, I just want to point out that I think this is usually BAD, it is not always ideal to use interface blocks or structs in SSBO. Here's an example:

Let's say you have a struct in C++ like this:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    glm::vec4 position;
    glm::vec4 velocity;
    glm::vec4 padding_and_range;  // range is a float padded to a vec4
};
```

which corresponds to an SSBO buffer in glsl:

```c
struct Foo {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 velocity;
    vec4 padding_and_range;  // range is a float padded to a vec4
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) readonly buffer SSBO {
    Foo data[];
} foo;
```

Although the SSBO buffer is able to hold an array of `struct Foo`, notice that paddings must be taken into account as per the `std430` memory layout, you have to padded your `float range` to a `vec4`, and then use `foo.data[i].padding_and_range.w` to access it. This is error-prone, let alone the waste of memory spaces, especially when your SSBO is large (to be used in a compute shader) and your `Foo` struct is complex (needs a lot of paddings). Apart from that, you often need to fill in the buffer data in a loop like this:

```cpp
Foo* foos = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(glMapNamedBufferRange(ssbo, offset, size, GL_MAP_READ_BIT));

for (int i = 0; i < n_foos; i++) {
    Foo& foo = foos[i];
    foo.position          = glm::vec4(1.0f);
    foo.velocity          = glm::vec4(2.0f);
    foo.padding_and_range = glm::vec4(glm::vec3(0.0f), 3.5f);
}

glUnmapNamedBuffer(ssbo);
```

instead of simply writing data to it in one go using `glNamedBufferData` or `glNamedBufferSubData`.

A better way of handling struct is to store each struct element into a separate SSBO, so that each SSBO buffer array is tightly packed and homogeneous. Even though the performance may not be any better, it helps keep your code clean and more readable. Rarher than using the struct, you would want to use:

```c
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer FooPosition {
  vec4 position[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer FooVelocity {
  vec4 velocity[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer FooRange {
  float range[];
};
```